# CSS background-color giving weird results in google chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I changed the background-color css property. The files are as follows:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>hi</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

main.css

```
body {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

In chrome:

[image: Background using Chrome]

In firefox:

[image: Background using Firfox]

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Here is the developer tools view on chrome:
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuG8S.png)

Comment: Is that the whole `main.css`?

Comment: Yes. That's it.

Comment: It may still be acceptable that the color blue had been rendered differently, but I'm curious as to where the violet color came from

Comment: _but I'm curious as to where the violet color came from_ @Swellar the same question I'm about to ask.

Comment: also the width and height of the div

Comment: That different color patch is not a div. It does not even get detected by the element inspector.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a hex value instead of the color name "blue"?

Perhaps try :

```
background-color: #0000FE;
```

This is the hex value for that color blue you are using, I believe.

Comment: I put the hex value there. Still color same output. The outer light color is #6F97FE. And the inner dark square is #6F00FE.

Comment: Could it perhaps be an issue with your software interfering with chrome somehow to produce this output? I know sometimes I have had a border or something visual appear around the object I was last working before launching the html file.

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the cache or refreshing the css file in the browser by viewing the source in the page.

Sometimes the cache may contain some definitions from previous programs.

Comment: I cleared site data and cache from application tab in the developer tools. Still no change.

Comment: open the css file in your browser through the developer tools and refresh that css page 

Then try once again

Comment: Just did that. Nothing changed. Also this fault comes on only specific colors, for eg. If I set background-color: pink; then the output is normal.

Comment: can u please share the code which comes @ the developer tools window.. 

please check for the <div> by inspecting it

Comment: I posted it on the question.

Comment: clear all browsing data or just try opening in incognito mode

Comment: Tried it. Still the same output.