# Why chrome shows weird color artifacts when using background-color?

Tags: css, google-chrome, background-color

When I try to add a solid color to the body tag with CSS, I get a weird dark square that I can't figure out where it came from.

I tried to google the issue but didn't find any answers.
I did find a stack overflow thread here before - it's before 5 years and no answer there:
[CSS background-color giving weird results in google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47448179/css-background-color-giving-weird-results-in-google-chrome)

Preview:
[image]

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>My Boilerplate</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```css
body {
    background: brown;
}
```

I tried to load the page in safari and it doesn't happen there, so it must be a chrome issue - is there a way to fix this? is this a known issue?

Edit:

- It shows on iMac Late 2015 (macOS Monterey)
- Doesn't show on MacBook Pro mid 2015 (macOS Mojave)
- Doesn't show on iPad
- Doesn't show in iPhone

Comment: I do not see the problem on Chrome Windows 10.

Comment: What version of browser you have?

Comment: Latest - Version 114.0.5735.133 (Official Build) (x86_64)

Answer (score 1):

Found this for you!

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=633805

if you paste this in your address bar it will fix your problem :)

```
chrome://flags/#enable-gpu-rasterization
```